# Css Position:sticky doesn't work only in MOBILE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, sticky

I'm having trouble on Chrome on sticky css. Only on the mobile browser one of the elements of the page does not assume the sticky position. 
[The problem can be seen on the following page](https://www.goatsplan.com/copywriting/)

Basically from the computer the following code has no problem, Instead from mobile the red bar at the top of the page does not take the defined position. This is the code I used:

```
.top-bar-copywriting {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky !important;
   top: 0 !important;
   z-index: 2;}
```

Anyone have an idea how the same problem can be solved ?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sticky is incorrect '!important' does not need to be there, nor does z-index

```
<style>
.top-bar-copywriting {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
<style>
<div class="top-bar-copywriting">
<div class="contentExample>
<h1> Words</h1>
<--!put content here!-->
</div>
</div>
```

Are you using safari? Safari might be incapable of running sticky things. You should get google.